# Finding the Basis of the second order homogenous ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following second order ODE
$$y'' + y = 0$$
First basis:
$$\cos t, \sin t$$
Another basis:
$$\sin \frac\pi4+ t, \sin\frac\pi4- t$$

Then

$$\sin (\fracπ4+ t)=1/\sqrt{2}\cos t+1/\sqrt{2}\sin t$$

$$\sin (\fracπ4- t)=1/\sqrt{2}\cos t-1/\sqrt{2}\sin t$$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\\1/\sqrt{2}&-1/\sqrt{2}\\\end{bmatrix}$$
Where $A$ is the change of basis matrix.

While i know thant the first basis is the Two Linearly independent solutions of the ODE. I am unsure of how to change the basis to get the second basis $\sin \fracπ4+ t,\sin \fracπ4- t$ and also how to check the basis to get the result above.And also i dont get the rationale of why must we find any basis when we already know one. Im stuck more at the linear algebra portion rather than at the ODE portion. Could anyoe please explain the linear algebra portion of this question to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As

$$\sin \left(\fracπ4+ t\right)=1/\sqrt{2}\cos t+1/\sqrt{2}\sin t$$

$$\sin \left(\fracπ4- t\right)=1/\sqrt{2}\cos t-1/\sqrt{2}\sin t$$

or

$$
\left(\matrix{\sin \left(\fracπ4+ t\right) \\ \sin \left(\fracπ4- t\right)}\right) =\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\\1/\sqrt{2}&-1/\sqrt{2}\\\end{bmatrix}\left(\matrix{\cos t \\ \sin t}\right)
$$

$A$ is called [basis change transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) which is bijective $(\det A \ne 0)$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\\1/\sqrt{2}&-1/\sqrt{2}\\\end{bmatrix}$$

now as $A^{-1}= A$ we have as well

$$
\left(\matrix{\cos t \\ \sin t}\right) =\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\\1/\sqrt{2}&-1/\sqrt{2}\\\end{bmatrix}\left(\matrix{\sin \left(\fracπ4+ t\right) \\ \sin \left(\fracπ4- t\right)}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

To check that they are a basis then they have to satisfy the differential equation and they  are linearly independent (check the [wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian))  . For instance

$$ (\sin(\pi/4+t))'' + \sin(\pi/4+t) =0 $$

and same for the other function.

Comment: Yup i know, but now what im unsure of is how to change the basis and also how to get the change of basis matrix $A$.Im stuck more at the linear algebra portion rather than the ODE portion.

Comment: @yswong: So why do you ask the question "Problem How do we check that it’s indeed a basis? "

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @yswong: You edited the question after you got the answer!

Comment: My problem lies with the Linear algebra portion not the ODE portion. Could u please explain.Thanks